# OpenLayers GeometryCollection styling issue

Tags: openlayers, javascript, geometry, style

With some help, I am able to draw some custom shape on my OpenLayers project with the following code.

```
    geometryFunction = function (coordinates, geometry) {
    const center = coordinates[0];
    const last = coordinates[coordinates.length - 1];
    const dx = center[0] - last[0];
    const dy = center[1] - last[1];
    const radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    const rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    const newCoordinates = [];
    let numPoints = 48;
    for (let i = 0; i < numPoints + 1; ++i) {
      const angle = rotation - Math.PI + (i * 1.5 * Math.PI) / numPoints;
      const offsetX = radius * Math.cos(angle);
      const offsetY = radius * Math.sin(angle);
      newCoordinates.push([center[0] + offsetX, center[1] + offsetY]);
    }
    const geometries = [new LineString(newCoordinates)];
    numPoints = 3;
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      const angle =
        rotation +
        Math.PI / 2 +
        ((i + 1) * 0.5 * Math.PI) / (numPoints + 1);
      const offsetX = radius * Math.cos(angle);
      const offsetY = radius * Math.sin(angle);
      geometries.push(
        new Point([center[0] + offsetX, center[1] + offsetY])
      );
    }
    if (!geometry) {
      geometry = new GeometryCollection();
    }
    geometry.setGeometries(geometries);
    return geometry;
  };
}
draw = new Draw({
  source: source,
  type: value,
  geometryFunction: geometryFunction
});
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

Now, the issue is, whenever I try to add a new shape with a text label, the other shapes with or without text labels  are also being modified with the new label. The code I am using to add text label is :-

```
 map.addInteraction(draw);
    draw.on("drawstart", function (event) {
      event.feature.setStyle(stylefunction);
    });

function stylefunction(feature, resolution) {
  var styles = {
    LineString: new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: "red",
        width: 2
      }),
      text: new Text({
        text: labelInput.value,
        fill: new Fill({
          color: "#000000"
        })
      })
    }),
    Point: new Style({
      image: new Icon({
        color: "#f00",
        scale: 0.1,
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",
        src: "cross.svg"
      })
    })
  };
  var geoms = feature.getGeometry().getGeometries();
  var length = geoms.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    var geom = geoms[i];
    var type = geom.getType();
    var style = styles[type];
    style.setGeometry(geom);
    stylesArray[i] = style;
  }
  stylesArray.length = length;
  return stylesArray;
}
```

You can find the working demo [here](https://5nk8sz.csb.app/)

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that you are referencing global value `labelInput.value` when defining text label in the style. This causes style to always reflect current value of `labelInput.value` when styling features.

One possible solution for this is to store current value of `labelInput.value` as feature property when the draw starts, something like:

```
draw.on("drawstart", function (event) {
  event.feature.setStyle(stylefunction);
  event.feature.set('txt', labelInput.value);
});
```

Then you can use this property in the style function when defining text label:

```
text: new Text({
  text: feature.get('txt'),
  fill: new Fill({
    color: "#000000"
  })
})
```

To have it all in one place, as per Mike's comment the `Point` style needs to be cloned instead of the same instance being pushed 3 times otherwise only the final geometry is set:

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  var geom = geoms[i];
  var type = geom.getType();
  var style = styles[type].clone();
  style.setGeometry(geom);
  stylesArray[i] = style;
}
```

Comment: Additionally the Point style needs to be cloned instead of the same instance being pushed 3 times otherwise only the final geometry is set https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-shapes-forked-re6okf?file=/main.js